# using icacls to assign one user to their specific username named folder

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs, icacls

So I have 200 folders each with a name created from a group in active directory.

for example.. C:/project/Users/ and within users i have a list of 200 folders ..

John Doe

Jane Doe

Adam Scott

Cabir Notad

and so on and so forth..

I need every folder to be assigned sharing permissions for their user specifically, as well as two groups.. So John Doe's folder needs permission for John Doe, IT Security Group, Copier. Same goes for Jane Doe, her folder needs permissions for Jane Doe,IT Security Group, Copier.

We cannot use groups for specific user permissions aside from the two security groups because each user can ONLY have access to their respective folder, they shouldn't be able to access other users files.

I found a script using icacls but it's not producing the results i'm after So i'm open to a power shell or any other script that might help.

Here is the script.. But I think it has a different purpose.. its called  Bulk replace owners of folders based on folder name

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path d:\home | Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true
}

foreach ($folder in $folders) 
{
    $path = $folder.fullname
    $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $path
    $user = $folder.name
    icacls.exe $path /setowner $user
}
```

I appreciate any assistance, i'm very surprised this seems like an uncommon request as i've been searching for days. Thanks again..

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to figure out how to use icacls with PowerShell to handle some logic for permissioning folders, I would point you to take a look this:
[Using iCalcs in PowerShell Winter Scripting Games](https://github.com/AdilHindistan/2014WinterScriptingGames/tree/master/WSG2014_03_Acl-Calc-Toil-and-Trouble)

It addresses a [more complex scenario](https://github.com/AdilHindistan/2014WinterScriptingGames/blob/master/WSG2014_03_Acl-Calc-Toil-and-Trouble/event-647112/event.docx) with full solution. It should give you plenty of amno to adapt it into your needs.

Comment: Answers that are essentially just a link to another page are not considered good answers on stackoverflow for a myriad of reasons. Plese rewrite this to provide an actual answer for the OP. Feel free to use the information in the link.

Comment: @EBGreen I am with you, but I do not have cycles to do that right now. I provided that link anyway b/c it actually would help someone who spent days searching for something useful.

Comment: @EBGreen I am not here for popularity/ego, but to help people.